# How to solve "TypeError: Internal or recursive type is not allowed for public state variables"? Solidity

Tags: solidity, mapping

I have the following mapping for the users stakes in solidity.

```
mapping(address => AllUserStakedTimestamp) internal allUserStakes;

struct AllUserStakedTimestamp {
    bool[] _wasUnstaked;
    bool[] _autoRenewal;
    uint[] _amountStaked;
    uint[] _timeOfStake;
    uint[] _timesOfRelease;
    uint[] _optionReleaseSelected; // 0-1-2
    uint[] _epochDuration;
    uint[] _rewardPerCycle;
    uint[] _finalStakeReward;
}
```

I have now finished to write the contract and need to retrieve some of this data from the front end / web3.js, but just now realized that I will encounter this error:

```
TypeError: Internal or recursive type is not allowed for public state variables.
--> 11 - NewPublic.sol:72:5:72 | mapping(address => AllUserStakedTimestamp) public allUserStakes;
```

How can I make the data available "public" without getting this error, as this struct is used by many other solidity functions and modifying it or splitting it into smaller parts will require pretty much a full rewrite of the functions and bugs search from the beginning.

Any suggesiton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, instead of rewriting the entire data structure I can create a public function that retrives the data like so:

```
function checkStakeByIndex(uint _stakeIndexNo) public view returns(
    string memory,                                                          // - 0 legend below:
    bool,                                                                   // - 1 WU  - was unstaked
    bool,                                                                   // - 2 AR  - automatic renewal
    uint,                                                                   // - 3 AS  - amount staked
    uint,                                                                   // - 4 TOS - time of stake
    uint                                                                    // - 5 TOR - time of release                                                                    // - 7 ED - epoch duration
    ){return(
    "1 - WU | 2 - AR | 3 - AS | 4 - TOS | 5 - TOR :",                       // - 0 legend below:
    allUserStakes[msg.sender]._wasUnstaked[_stakeIndexNo],                  // - 1 WU  - was unstaked
    allUserStakes[msg.sender]._autoRenewal[_stakeIndexNo],                  // - 2 AR  - automatic renewal
    allUserStakes[msg.sender]._amountStaked[_stakeIndexNo],                 // - 3 AS  - amount staked
    allUserStakes[msg.sender]._timeOfStake[_stakeIndexNo],                  // - 4 TOS - time of stake
    allUserStakes[msg.sender]._timesOfRelease[_stakeIndexNo]);              // - 5 TOR - time of release                 
    }
```

It's not the prettiest but better then changing all the code and everything else that inherited from that data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by implementing an explicit getter function, no need to make major modifications. See this example:

```
mapping(address => AllUserStakedTimestamp) internal allUserStakes;

struct AllUserStakedTimestamp {
    bool[] _wasUnstaked;
    bool[] _autoRenewal;
    uint[] _amountStaked;
    uint[] _timeOfStake;
    uint[] _timesOfRelease;
    uint[] _optionReleaseSelected; // 0-1-2
    uint[] _epochDuration;
    uint[] _rewardPerCycle;
    uint[] _finalStakeReward;
}

function getUsersStakes(address user) external view returns (AllUserStakedTimestamp memory) {
    return allUserStakes[user];
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, if I do I get the error I copy pasted, hence my question.

Comment: @SkylerX If that's the case, I'm not sure why that error would happen with the above code. We may need to see more of the contract to understand

Comment: the error happens because in solidity you can not make public a mapping with nested arrays, but I would like to find a solution to avoid changing the data structure.

Comment: @SkylerX Ahhh okay, I understand your issue now. I edited my answer above to give a more relevant answer

Answer (score 0):

```
mapping(address => AllUserStakedTimestamp) public allUserStakes;

struct AllUserStakedTimestamp {
    bool[] _wasUnstaked;
    bool[] _autoRenewal;
    uint[] _amountStaked;
    uint[] _timeOfStake;
    uint[] _timesOfRelease;
    uint[] _optionReleaseSelected; // 0-1-2
    uint[] _epochDuration;
    uint[] _rewardPerCycle;
    uint[] _finalStakeReward;
}
```

That will do. There you have to give public instead of internal.

Just know there are four types of function visibility in the solidity:

- Public
- Private
- Internal
- External.

**Public**: The function can be called by anyone both from inside the contract and outside the contract.

**Private**: The function is only available inside the contract. When you assign this visbility, the function isn't even available to inherit.

**Internal**: Just like the private but it supports inheritance. You can inherit the function.

**External**: Function can only be accessed by outside the contract. If the function visibility is external, that means it is not accessable internally.

You can read more about the function visibilities [here](https://www.developer.com/languages/variable-function-visibility-solidity/).

Tell me if it helps!

Comment: thanks for reply, if I do I get the error I copy pasted, hence my question.